# Resetting commit

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

**Need Help with SourcedTree:**

Hello, I am using SourceTree (Windows) for code synchronization within a repository. I have checked out tutorials and other sources, but I am still confused.

To be clear, I am interested in SourceTree, not the git concept.

***For example:***

Lets say I want to reset my commit to older one and then push it as new commit. What is the best way to do that? And is there are any good guides/tutorials on how to use SourceTree?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some infornation about SourceTree you can find here https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/SOURCETREEKB/SourceTree+Knowledge+Base+Home

But in your situation you must:

1. Pick commit that you want to reset in tree panel.
2. Click right button on mouse
3. Select option 'Reset brunch to this commit'